# GNS construction and separability.

Tags: hilbert-spaces, c-star-algebras, von-neumann-algebras, separable-spaces

Start with a $C^*$-algebra $\mathcal{A}$ and take an state (positive normalized linear functional). Then build its GNS representation and get the GNS Hilbert space $\mathcal{H}_{GNS}$. The questions are:

Q1) If $\mathcal{A}$ is separable (in the $C^*$ norm topology), then $\mathcal{H}_{GNS}$ is separable?

Q2) If we start with other Hilbert space $\mathcal{H}$, and consider the algebra of all bounded operators $\mathcal{A} = \mathcal{B}(\mathcal{H})$ and a (normalized) vector state $\Psi \in \mathcal{H}$. It's know that $\mathcal{B}(\mathcal{H})$ is not separable. But, is $\mathcal{H}_{GNS}$ separable?

I will find very helpful any bibliography (theorems, examples, counterexamples) about separability of the GNS representation? For example, a challenger question:

Q3) If the original $C^*$-algebra was indeed a  $W^*$-algebra (or a von Neumann algebra), is there any relation between the type of algebra (I, II, III, etc.) and/or the fact the state is/isn't normal, with the separability of $\mathcal{H}_{GNS}$?

Thanks,

D

Answer (score 4):

1. Yes, the Hilbert space is separable. Suppose that $\{b_n\}$ is a dense sequence in $\mathcal A$. Note that $\mathcal H$ is constructed as the closure of (a quotient of ) $\mathcal A$. Given $h\in \mathcal H$, by construction there exists a sequence $\{a_n\}\subset \mathcal A$ with $\hat a_n\to h$. Now let $b_{k_n}\in \mathcal A$ with $\|a_n-b_{k_n}\|<1/2^n$. Then 
   $$\tag1
   \|h-\hat b_{k_n}\|\leq\|h-\hat a_n\|+\|\hat a_n-\hat b_{k_n}\|,
   $$
   and $$\tag2\|\hat a_n-\hat b_{k_n}\|^2=f((a_n-b_{k_n})^*(a_n-b_{k_n}))\leq\|a_n-b_{k_n}\|^2
   $$
   Then $(1)$ and $(2)$ together imply 
   $$
   \limsup\|h-\hat b_{n_k}\|\leq\limsup 1/2^n=0.
   $$
2. If you take a vector state $\psi$, you have $\psi=\langle \cdot \,e_1,e_1\rangle$ for some $e_1\in\mathcal H$ with $\|e_1\|=1$. Complete to an orthonormal basis $\{e_n\}$. You have $$\psi(A)=\text{Tr}\,(E_{11}A)=A_{11}.$$ When you do GNS, you need to quotient by the subspace 
   $$
   \mathcal H_0=\{A\in \mathcal{B(H)}:\ \psi(A^*A)=0\}. 
   $$
   The condition $\psi(A^*A)=0$ is the same as $AE_{11}=E_{11}A=0$. So $B-A\in \mathcal H_0$ if and only if $E_{11}B=E_{11}A$, $BE_{11}=AE_{11}$. That is, $\mathcal{H_{\psi}=B(H)/H_0}$ is spanned by the classes of $E_{11}, E_{12}, E_{13},\ldots$, and $E_{21}, E_{31}, E_{41},\ldots$. Being spanned by a countable set, $\mathcal H_\psi$ is separable.
3. When $\psi$ is any normal state, if $M$ is separable then so is $\mathcal H_\psi$. Suppose that $X=\{b_n\}\subset M$ is dense and countable. Using Kaplansky, we may tweak $X$ so that any $a\in M$ is a limit of a bounded net in $X$ (basically, write $X=\bigcup_nX_n$, where $X_n$ is the set obtained by applying the Kaplansky function to the elements of $X$ so that they approach those elements of $M$ with norm less than $n$). Now, given $a\in M$, there exists a net $\{b_j\}$ in $X$ with $b_j\to a$ in the $\sigma$-weak topology. Now
   \begin{align}
   \|b_j-a\|^2&=\psi((b_j-a)^*(b_j-a))=\psi(b_j^*b_j)+\psi(a^*a)-2\operatorname{Re}a^*b_j
   \to 0,
   \end{align}
   where the limit works because $\{b_j\}$ is bounded. So $\hat X$ is dense in $\mathcal H_\psi$.

I don't think type has anything to do with it.

Comment: Muchas gracias!

Comment: And about your feeling on Q3, I have a "counter feeling": in algebraic QFT (Haag, Kastler approach) the local algebras are infinite dimensional von Neumann algebras (expected to be type III) and the vacuum state is cyclic and separating for such algebras, and hence faithful. I don't expect (or it will be a very surprising for me) that the GNS Hilbert space obtained from the vacuum and a local algebra will be non-separable. It just a feeling, inspired in the idea among the physicists  that (almost) always the Hilbert spaces are separable.

Comment: @martin argerami. Regarding three, my intuition is the opposite, I would say that if $\psi$ is a normal state and the algebra $M$ is separable (as a von Neumann algebra) then $H_{GNS}$ is separable. The proof will be by taking a cyclic vector $\xi$ and a countable weak-$\ast$ dense subset $S$ of $M$ will a dense countable sent $S \xi$. It may be that the converse is not correct.

Comment: You guys are right. I have changed the answer to include a small argument in the normal case.